# nginx unicorn - POST flask_mail 502 error and 'Ignoring connection reset

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have tested my app on local computer but when I tried it on nginx + gunicorn I get 502 error and

> [2018-05-15 21:36:21 +0000] [12849] [DEBUG] Ignoring connection reset

check nginx log

> upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

I edit nginx settings to this:

```
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;
```

and starting gunicorn this way:

```
GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS=" --workers 1 --threads 4 --timeout 300" gunicorn app:app --log-level=debug
```

I have got still same error